# Using CSS object-fit:contain on image leaves blank spaces around it

Tags: html, css, object-fit

I have a container `image-wrapper` and an image inside it.

The container has a fixed height and width. Inside it, the image resolution will be dynamic.

All I am trying to do is to center the image to the container, horizontally and vertically and apply some `box-shadow` styling to it.

But it leaves a blank space around the image, and it looks weird. Below is the code. It happens same with a vertical image.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(0,200,100);
  padding: 40px;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200">
</div>
```

I want to have a shadow around the image only, without the spaces. I think I am missing a very simple thing here.

I have tried to add `position: relative` to the container, but it didn't work.

I tried to search about it by searching something like "**css object fit image shadow**", "**css object fit on image adds spaces**" and didn't found anything similar to it.

Comment: object-fit:cover instead of contain

Comment: @TemaniAfif the image should not be cropped from any side. I cannot use it. I was planning on using as a background image but the requirements changed.

Comment: remove height:100% then from the the image

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height: 100%;` and `object-fit: contain;` from `.image-wrapper img`

Also, remove `height: 400px;` from the `.image-wrapper`.

To centre image use CSS Grid: *(btw, it is not required to center in this condition)*

```
display: grid;
place-items: center;
```

```css
.image-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 100);
  padding: 40px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000">
</div>
```

**Some useful resources:**

- [object-fit Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- [place-items Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items)
- [place-items Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#place-items)

Comment: No no, the image should not be cropped. It should show the full image inside the container. And also should be center aligned.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Then the image will be not in proper shape!

Comment: You see, `object-fit: contain` does exactly the thing, I mean it center aligns the image without distorting it, maintaining it's aspect ratio. It is in proper shape, but not the box-shadow. :(

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul The image you are using is `500x200` and the size of the box is `400x400`, then how will you make them equal

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul I have updated it, as you told ... Now the box-shadow is of the size of image

Comment: Thank you Manas, yes it does looks exactly as required. But it does not work with a vertical image. You can see it overflowing if you try with a `500x1000` image.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul I have updated the answer !

Answer (score 1):

My solution without cropped and with Flexbox :

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(0,200,100);
  padding: 40px;
  display : flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000">
</div>
```

Comment: I will give it a try and will give you an update.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyBeaumecker I tried it, it works fine with this image in the question. But if the image is vertical, say `500x1000` it overflows the container.

Comment: I edited with an image with 1000px in height. It's worked

Comment: Yes it does work! Only downside is it has a fixed width. I have to figure out if I can get around this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this solution:

As per the requirement,

1. the container has a fixed height and width. Hence, added the following to class `.image-wrapper`

```
      height: 400px;
      width: 400px;
```

2. image is to be centred in the container, horizontally and vertically. Hence, added the following to class `.image-wrapper`

```
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
```

3. To prevent blank space around the image when box-shadow is added, instead of height and width, added max-height and max-width to the `img`. This will prevent height and width of the image from going more than 400px parent, and the aspect ratio of the image will also be maintained.

```
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
```

Overall, this is the solution:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 100);
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x200">
</div>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x1000">
</div>
```